# execute before_filter/before_action for all subresources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a model and a controller 'Parent'. It has a bunch of `has_many` relationships: children, cars, food, etc, and each has a controller.

Parent has a field called 'dead'. When `dead: true`, I want all children relationships to display a particular message on their `#show` and `#index` pages.

I could just put a lot of `if statements` everywhere i want a check

```
if self.parent.dead
  <show special message>
end
```

A cleaner way is to put that in a `before_filter`. Still, I need to do it for every child controller. So I guess the question is, is there a clean way of executing something for all dependent records? I want a behaviour somewhat similar to `dependent: :destroy`, only I'm not actually deleting anything, i just want to executer `before_filter` for all dependent records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define that in a concern and you can include that concern in whichever child controller you want to display the message in.

Comment: That's basically my solution at the moment :) Was hoping rails could assist in doing something cleverer. I'll wait for a bit longer and if noone has a better idea will accept this one.